# Using implicit differentation to find the tangent to $3xy=y^2$

Tags: calculus

> Use implicit differentiation to find
>   the equation of the line tangent to
>   the graph of $3xy = y^2$ at $(1,3)$

This is what I tried so far:
$$\begin{align*}
3\frac{d}{dx}(x)\frac{d}{dx}(y(x)) &= \frac{d}{dx}(y(x)^2)\\
3(1)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) &= 2\frac{dy}{dx}\\
3 &= \frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align*}$$

Then using that to solve the equation, I get:
$$\begin{align*}
y-3 &= 3(x-1)\\
y &= 3x
\end{align*}$$

Did I solve this correctly?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I would actually have:
$$\begin{align*}
3\left (\frac{dx}{dx}y+\frac{dy}{dx}(x)\right) &= 2y\frac{dy}{dx}\\
3\left(y+x\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right) &= 2y\frac{dy}{dx}\\
3\left(3+1\frac{dy}{dx}\right) &= 2(3)\frac{dy}{dx}\\
9+3\frac{dy}{dx} &= 6\frac{dy}{dx}\\
3 &= \frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align*}$$
Then using that to solve the equation, I get:
$$\begin{align*}
y-3 &= 3(x-1)\\
y &= 3x
\end{align*}$$

Comment: No. Look at the first line and remember the product and chain rules. It should be $\frac{d}{dx}(xy) = y + \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2) = 2y\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: @jspecter - Question edited

Comment: You are missing a $3$ in the first line after the edit (though the omission is corrected in the second line).

Comment: And you still need to take that $3 = \frac{dy}{dx}$ and use it to answer the question asked: you want the equation of the tangent, not just the value of the derivative.

Comment: I thought that was the only thing I got right in the first draft, lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You computed both derivatives incorrectly.

For $\frac{d}{dx}(xy)$, you need to use the product rule. You get
$$\frac{d}{dx}(xy) = \left(\frac{dx}{dx}\right)y + x \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right).$$

And for $\frac{d}{dx}y^2$, you need to use the Chain Rule. You get
$$\frac{d}{dx}y^2 = 2y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right).$$

---

Once you've correctly computed the implicit derivative, you can proceed as you did before: plug in $x=1$ and $y=3$, and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. That gives the slope of the tangent at $(1,3)$. Then use the point-slope formula to get the equation of the tangent.

**By the way.** I always tell my students to check explicitly whether the given point is *actually* on the given curve before starting to do computations. You might want to do that (in this case, it *is*).

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: So, I fell into the right answer by mistake? Because I did that and still got $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3$

Comment: @Oghma: Well, you solved for $y'$ incorrectly the first time (so you made *lots* of mistakes). If you really had $3y' = 2y'$, your conclusion *should* have been $y'=0$ (just subtract $2y'$ from both sides); I don't know how you managed to get $y'=3$ in the first go around.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno either.... now that I look at it, lol.